# How do I redirect old ugly looking urls to new SEO friendly urls?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I really need some help figuring this out since I've been trying to solve this problem for couple of days already.

I had old urls that looked like this:
category.php?id=6&name=maxi-dresses&type=1**

I have changed them to look like this using htaccess: **https://markandroberts.com/category/dresses/maxi-dresses/**

As you can noticed, in the new urls I have also changed the position of the category id by putting it at the end instead at the beginning.

What I want to do now is to 301 redirect all the old category urls that are already indexed in Google to the new location.

Here's my current htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.markandroberts.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)/$^ product.php?id=$1&type=$2&name=$3
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)/ product.php?id=$1&type=$2&name=$3

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)/$^ category.php?type=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)/ category.php?type=$1&id=$2

RewriteRule ^type/(.*)$/^ main-category.php?maincat=$1
RewriteRule ^type/(.*)/ main-category.php?maincat=$1

RedirectMatch 301 /category.php?id=$1&name=$2&type=$3 /category/$3/$1/
```

Any solutions that work?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Share what effort you put in to sort this problem.

Comment: sure, here's my htaccess: 
RedirectMatch 301 /category.php?id=$1&name=$2&type=$3 /category/$3/$1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `.htaccess` file to include some "pretty url" rules. [Here](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) is an example for you.